# "Job for system-cloudinit@-var-tmp-hostname.yml.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded"

Tags: vagrant, systemd, rancher

I am starting using Rancher and Vagrant to create my local environment for development. Steps that I've done:

1. I already had VirtualBox installed.
2. I download and installed the Vagrant package for linux with

   ```
   sudo rpm -i vagrant_1.7.2_x86_64.rpm
   ```

Vagrant version:

```
vagran --version  
Vagrant 1.7.2
```

I cloned the Rancher repo from GitHub:

```
git clone git@github.com:rancherio/rancher.git
```

Which has the Vagrant file. After executing:

```
sudo vagrant up
```

Which is the step where I get the error, I got this:

```
==> rancher: Box 'coreos-alpha' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
rancher: Box Provider: virtualbox
rancher: Box Version: >= 308.0.1
==> rancher: Loading metadata for box 'http://alpha.release.core-os.net/amd64-usr/current/coreos_production_vagrant.json'
rancher: URL: http://alpha.release.core-os.net/amd64-usr/current/coreos_production_vagrant.json
==> rancher: Adding box 'coreos-alpha' (v709.0.0) for provider: virtualbox
rancher: Downloading: http://alpha.release.core-os.net/amd64-usr/709.0.0/coreos_production_vagrant.box
rancher: Calculating and comparing box checksum...
==> rancher: Successfully added box 'coreos-alpha' (v709.0.0) for 'virtualbox'!
==> rancher: Importing base box 'coreos-alpha'...
==> rancher: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> rancher: Checking if box 'coreos-alpha' is up to date...
==> rancher: Setting the name of the VM:rancher_rancher_1434213461241_51852
==> rancher: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> rancher: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
rancher: Adapter 1: nat
rancher: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> rancher: Forwarding ports...
rancher: 8080 => 8080 (adapter 1)
rancher: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> rancher: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> rancher: Booting VM...
==> rancher: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
rancher: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
rancher: SSH username: core
rancher: SSH auth method: private key
rancher: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
rancher: 
rancher: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
rancher: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
rancher: 
rancher: Inserting generated public key within guest...
rancher: Removing insecure key from the guest if its present...
rancher: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> rancher: Machine booted and ready!
==> rancher: Setting hostname...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!  

systemctl start system-cloudinit@-var-tmp-hostname.yml.service  

Stdout from the command:  



Stderr from the command:

Job for system-cloudinit@-var-tmp-hostname.yml.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded. See "systemctl status system-cloudinit@-var-tmp-hostname.yml.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Then when I go to the localhost:8080 there is no Rancher UI installed.

Comment: Could you log in into your docker instance and execute `systemctl status system-cloudinit@-var-tmp-hostname.yml.service` after the failure.

Comment: I got this:  system-cloudinit@-var-tmp-hostname.yml.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Answer (score 7):

I also encounter the same problem,
then I config the "config.rb", change the update channel to stable as below,

```
$update_channel='stable'
```

then destroy and up vagrant coreos again,

```
$ vagrant destroy
$ vagrant up
```

finally, the vagrant running successfully ~

Answer (score 1):

See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues/382), it's caused by an update in systemd in CoreOS 709.0.0.

Like smalltown mentions, you can switch back to an older version of CoreOS by using the beta channel. Or you can wait for this [this pull request](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-vagrant/pull/243) to be merged for vagrant-coreos so you can pin a specific version to use.